# Session PHP funciona en Firefox pero se pierde despues de ser usado en 3 páginas en Chrome

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

Verán, ya se me estaba presentando este problema en todos los navegadores, pero era debido a que utilizaba meta de html para redireccionar las páginas, así que cambié a Javascript: `window.location='mi_pagina.php';`.

Cuando utilizo Chrome, inicio sesión normal usando `$_SESSION` y me redirecciona a la primera página, pero una vez aquí si actualizo o redirecciono de nuevo se pierden las cookies. Sin embargo me funciona perfecto en Firefox.

Se presenta este problema sin importar el tipo de usuario o la página a la que ingrese.

**Aclaro que esto me pasa en el hosting. Localmente funciona perfecto en todos los navegadores.**

Les agradezco mucho de antemano.

---

El problema se había solucionado a medias cuando usé `session_cache_limiter('public');`, ya que aparte de que a veces se perdía cuando actualizaba la página no me traía datos cuando consultaba y no me realizaba las validaciones en PHP, lo que no entiendo porque PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor.

¿Las cookies requieren del caché?, tengo entendido que no.

Me ayudarían demasiado si me dijeran cómo puedo actualizar una página una sola vez cuando carga el caché.

Intenté creando una sesión para que se actualice si es igual a `SI`, pero cuando se cargaba la página del caché no se realiza esta actualización.

¿PHP siempre se actualiza aun con caché, cierto?

Comment: tus páginas php deben empezar así: `<?php
session_start();` ¿Lo hacen?

Comment: Este es el código que estoy utilizando al principio de la página: <?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
ob_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();} 
?>

Comment: En efecto tengo el session_start(); al principio de la página

Comment: CABALLEROS, EL ASUNTO ES QUE ME FUNCIONA NORMAL EN FIREFOX, PERO SE PIERDE $_SESSION DESPUÉS DE INICIAR SESIÓN EN CHROME SIN IMPORTAR CUÁL DE LAS PÁGINAS ABRA

Comment: También lo probé en otros equipos; limpié el caché y las cookies, borré el historial, y nada

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema guardando el caché desde el index mientras la aplicación está activa.

Muchas gracias por su interés

Comment: Me podrias explicar como se hace por favor

Comment: Hola, podrias publicar como lo resolviste mas especifico por favor. y otra pregunta de casualidad eres jugador de shaiya?